# Nesting a PHP string with a SQL command into another SQL insert statement

Tags: php, sql

```
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO pics (filename) VALUES ('$fileName')";
$results_insert = $conn->query($sql_insert);

$max = "SELECT pic_id FROM pics WHERE pic_id = (SELECT MAX(pic_id) FROM pics)";

$sql_update = "UPDATE users 
            SET pic_id = '$max'
            WHERE username = '$username'" ;
```

The error I am receiving is:

> Error: Unknown column 'pic_id' in 'field list'

I am not sure how to nest a PHP string with a SQL command into another `SQL` insert statement. I have already double checked that the `pics` table exists as well as the `pic_id` column.

EDIT: I am now trying to use PDO to accomplish this.

```
$t = $pdo->beginTransaction();

$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT MAX(pic_id) FROM pics');
$sth -> execute();
$pic_id = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sth = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :username, password = :password, email = :email, name = :name, country_id = :country_id, pic_id = :pic_id WHERE username = :username');
$sth->bindParam(':pic_id', $pic_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO pics (pic_id, filename, filepath) VALUES (:pic_id, :fileName, :resized_file)');
$sth->bindParam(':fileName', $fileName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$pdo->commit();
```

The reason why I moved the insert into the `pics` table below the `users` table was because the `pic_id` in `pics` references the `pic_id` in `users`. I am however still getting the same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pic_id' in 'field list'

Comment: It is looking for a table in the database called 'field list'. That aint right. Include the entire PHP script in your question.

Comment: have you tried `WHERE pic_id IN (SELECT...`  ?  that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of programs (MySQLI, PDO) have methods that will return the ID of the last inserted item, but I'm not really sure what program you're using to interact with your database.

#### Generic Method

```
SELECT pic_id FROM pics ORDER BY pic_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

#### MySQLI Method

```
$max = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

#### PDO Method

```
$max = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PDO and binding parameters instead of using PHP string values. Also I suppose you should do all these operations within one transaction. So I'd rewrite code as follow:

```
$t = $pdo->beginTransaction();

$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO pics (filename) VALUES (:fileName)');
$sth->bindParam(':fileName', $fileName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$sth = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET pic_id = :id WHERE username = :username');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

$pdo->commit();
```

Comment: Also please check that column `pic_id` exists in table `users`

Comment: also i have double checked that pic_id exists

Comment: Fatal error should contain the line number. It should point out the statement where the error occured. Is it insertion in `pics` or update or `users`?